# How can add static Block as a category cms block

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to display extension static block as a category cms block.

```
Its working as a Extensions.
```

[image]

```
But not working as a category cms block static
```

[image]

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/XskfIPv.png

Comment: not working at my end

Comment: have you tries for another category by adding that static block whether that is working or not.

Comment: no, not working

Comment: how can add static block as a page

Comment: create one page from cms-->pages, then call static block in that page.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/XskfIPv.png

Comment: share front end also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45137/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-teja-bhagavan-kollepara).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45140/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-teja-bhagavan-kollepara).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to `adminpanel->system->permission->block`

and click on `add Button` and add your block `formbuilder/frontend_form`

and click on save and flush magento cache and check

Comment: You are always welcome